# Taylor Expansion with Integral Remainder Question

Tags: integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have the following question at hand and I have to admit that I am not used to integral remainder form of taylor approximation. I am still trying to work around, so a couple of hints would be useful before a full answer.

Basically I have to determine the constant $c$ such that:

$\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\int\limits_{x}^{1}t^2f(t)dt + \frac{x^8}{8}+\frac{x^6}{6}-\frac{c}{24}$

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that:

$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$

I suppose thats important. And f is continuous, although I would imagine that is implicit...

EDIT_2:
Now, I would like to know if there is any other trickier solution or any approach using the integral remainder form of taylor expansion. Thanks!

Comment: Have you been told what $f(t)$ is or are you suggesting that this equation holds for any function? Only it doesn't hold for arbitrary $f(t)$.

Comment: The question seems somewhat incomplete.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that f is continous and from closed [0,1] to reals. See edit above.

Comment: If you subs $x=0$ in the equation, you will get $\frac{c}{24}=-\int_{0}^{1} t^2f(t) dt$.

Comment: My attempt at the solution (and I suppose its right):

With $x=0$, I got $\frac{c}{24}=\int_{0}^{1} t^2f(t) dt $ like Mhenni Benghorbal suggested.

Comment: Now, differentiating with respect to x on both sides and using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we get:

$f(x)=-x^2f(x)+x^7+x^5$ and rearranging:

$f(x)=\frac{x^7+x^5}{1+x^2}$

Now we need to find:

$\int\limits_{0}^{1}t^2f(t)dt=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{t^9+t^7}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{1}{8}$ and hence, $c=3$.

Comment: Now, I would like to know if there is any other trickier solution or any approach using the integral remainder form of taylor expansion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Plugging in $x=0$ and $x=1$ in the desired identity, one sees that
$$
24\int_0^1t^2f(t)\,\mathrm dt=c=7-24\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm dt.
$$
There is no reason to expect that the LHS and the RHS coincide hence, in general, there is no $c$ such that the identity holds for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ (and in fact, for $x=0$ and $x=1$).

Finding $f$ such that the identity holds is another question: assuming that $f$ is a solution and differentiating with respect to $x$ yields $f(x)=-x^2f(x)+x^7+x^5$, hence $f(x)=x^5$. This is indeed a solution and, using the LHS of the identity above, one sees that $c=24\cdot\frac18=3$.

Comment: Neither Taylor expansion nor integral remainder here.